# Is there a simple solution to avoid migration changes from ngx-bootstrap v5.1.2 to v6.2.0?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I have a very big angular project which uses ngx-bootstrap v5.1.2, now I want to migrate to ngx-bootstrap v6.2.0. I am forced to change import statements in lot of files, is there any simple solution to prevent changing import statements in all files.

**Present import statements in components**

```
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

**Need to change to**

```
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
```

I am using ngx-bootstrap from a shared folder. Is there a simple workaround to prevent changes in all files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the extract from official docs

```typescript
// RECOMMENDED
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';
// NOT RECOMMENDED (Angular 9 doesn't support this kind of import)
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
```

So basically If you do not migrate as recommended and upgrade to Angular 9+ then your app will not work as expected.

In short the only workaround is not to migrate... which is totally not recommended. So my advice, change all the imports. It may take a while but once you are done you will see some performance improvement in your app